# Excel-DNA: F# Error Initialization [Error] Method not registered

Tags: f#, excel-dna

As a neophyte F# developer, I am trying to create a simple Excel-DNA function as follows:

```
[<ExcelFunction(Name="ACount", Description="Count items", Category="Misc Functions", IsThreadSafe = true)>]
let aCount (range: _[]) (filter: string) = 
    let result = 
        Seq.ofArray range
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x = filter)
        |> Seq.length
    result
```

but it  generates the following error on loading to Excel 2016 (64-bit):

> Initialization [Error] Method not registered - 
>   unsupported signature, abstract or generic:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you replace `_[]` with `string []`? What is the type of the function of you hover on it?

Comment: Fyodor, Thanks for the quick follow-up. As requested:
   val aCount : range:string [] -> filter:string -> int

Comment: String arrays are not supported by Excel-DNA by default (without using the Registration extensions). Change to object[] arrays by casting the result valus to obj.

Comment: Govert, Are you saying I need to convert incoming string[] to object[] and / or outgoing int to object or both?

Comment: I mean it should work if the signature ends up being `val aCount : range:obj [] -> filter:string -> int`. Excel has conversions for int to double, but not for string arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Govert.

The following works but is it sufficiently idiomatic?

```
[<ExcelFunction(Name="ACount", Description="Count items", Category="Misc Functions", IsThreadSafe = true)>]
let aCount (range: obj[]) (filter: string) = 
    let result = 
        Seq.ofArray range
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> string x = filter)
        |> Seq.length
    result
```

Any constructive changes welcome!