# Polymorphism in Excel Dna / F#

Tags: f#, excel-dna

In F# / Excel-Dna, what is the idiomatic way to rewrite the following function for a vector of strings? (i.e. a function which sorts a "vector" (=1d Excel range) of strings).

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category="Some Cat", Description="Sort 1d range filled with doubles.")>]
    let mySortDouble (vect : double[]) : double[] = 
        Array.sort vect
```

If I merely replace the double types with string types in the above snippet, I get this error message : `Initialization [Error] Method not registered - unsupported signature, abstract or generic: 'MyFSFunctions.mySortString'`

I saw [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407760/excel-dna-f-error-initialization-error-method-not-registered) where Govert suggests to use the "Registration extensions" but I have not found how to use it to answer my current question.

Answer (score 4):

As you have mySortDouble written, it won't even compile, because it returns a double[], not a double.

Here's an example that works, with some minimal error handling added.

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category="Some Cat", Description="Sort 1D range of strings.")>]
let SortStrings (vect : obj[]) = 
    try
        vect
        |> Seq.cast<string>
        |> Seq.sort
        |> Seq.toArray
        |> box
    with
    | ex -> box ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA
```

Answer (score 1):

[For Registration samples](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/master/Source/Samples/Registration.Sample.FSharp/ExampleAddIn.fs#L14)

`ParameterConversionConfiguration()
            .AddReturnConversion(fun (values: double[]) ->
                Array.map (string >> box) values
            )`